# CSS file gets printed while hitting html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

To avoid cache, i included my css and js files through script tag.It generates a random number which will be added as query string to the files.

```
 <script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"/>');</script>
```

But most of times, when i hit the url, instead the html page, the css file is getting print directly in the browser

is the content header is causing the issue, should i need to add "type" parameter for css> Please provide me a soultion

Comment: You have `<script>` add the end of your string. Stylesheets are loaded via a self-closing `link` tag

Comment: as in remove the first <\/script>

Comment: `To avoid cache, i included my css and js files through script tag` - That's a pretty nasty habit you've got there.

Comment: <script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\>');</script>

Comment: It looks like they are doing the same thing here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Comment: Sorry, the script tag at the end is error while pasting it here. I have edited it now

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to stop caching. What if JS is disabled?

```
<script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\>');</script>
```

Comment: There should not be a closing `link` tag.

Answer (score 2):

If youre looking to speed things up in regards to your css and js files have you looked into script [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). That will speed your page up and remove clutter from your markup. Also, its mostly almost exclusively going to be Also look [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```